# Long running PHP script makes httpd.exe use huge amount of memory

Tags: php, apache, memory-leaks, imap

I've written a script that connects to a mail server to download all attachments and store them on a database.

Since the mailbox is very large, and the mail server is quite slow, it takes a few hours to complete.

After processing about 10.000 messages (message count is not exact and varies), the script dies with error: "PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 7077888) (tried to allocate 2815819 bytes)"

I've checked Task Manager and the memory usage of httpd.exe process gradually rises up to 1.5GB (after 1 and a half hours while the script is running), altough memory_get_usage() placed within the loop constantly reports something about 351.33kB, wich doesn't make me feel that there is a leak in my script. And even if there is a leak, how am I supposed to check it?

I'm running Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) with PHP/5.4.16 (SAPI) on Windows Server 2008 R2

My loop consists of reading email content with imap functions and storing attachment contents in database, one by one

I have switched to memory_get_usage(true), wich reported almost constantly 1.25MB

Comment: Why are you running this in the webserver SAPI in the first place: if it takes so long to run, you should be running it as a background task from the command line

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree. It WILL run on CLI after it is finished. But will that solve the issue? I could also restart the process every 50 messages or so (i keep track of last message, so restarting wouldn't be an issue). That would keep memory usage very low, but I still wouldn't know the cause of the problem.

Comment: No it won't solve the issue, but as we have no idea how your code is written we can't suggest much else beyond don't hold large volumes of data in memory

Comment: Well something is trying to grab a large chunk of memory (2,815,819 bytes, nearly 3MB) in one go, likely a large attachment.... but what are your php.ini memory settings?

Comment: @MarkBaker It is expected to try to grab some MB while fetching attachments. But the Fatal error ocurrs when the server's memory gets full. Answering your question, i'm using memory_limit: 256M. That limit wasn't hit, because the error would be "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted". Also, that proves PHP isn't counting that 1,5GB as being allocated by my script, when in fact, it is, maybe just indirectly